# How to filter PDF text by font?

Tags: python, pdf

[PDF example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddg3N.png)

A PDF may contain multiple fonts, how can I only keep 1 font with the most words with Python?

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer**: I am the author of `borb` (the library I will use in this example)

Oddly enough, there is an fairly close match example in the `borb` examples repository for filtering by font. You can find that example [here](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#581-filtering-by-font).

In this example, we extract all the text in a particular font in the PDF (e.g. all text written in `Courier`).

You can easily base yourself on this code to build something that checks the number of characters for each particular font (and at a later stage, return only the font with the most characters).

I'll repeat the example here for completeness:

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.text.font_name_filter import FontNameFilter
from borb.toolkit.text.simple_text_extraction import SimpleTextExtraction


def main():

    # create FontNameFilter
    l0: FontNameFilter = FontNameFilter("Courier")

    # filtered text just gets passed to SimpleTextExtraction
    l1: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    l0.add_listener(l1)

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l0])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print the names of the Fonts
    print(l1.get_text_for_page(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Aside from the imports, everything is quite straightforward. You specify the string of the font you want to filter on. This filter object will process the parsing/rendering of the PDF, and will only push events to its children if they are relevant (if the font information matches).

We add `SimpleTextExtraction` as its child, and so doing only get the text which is rendered in the desired font.

After we've set up this entire thing, we need to actually process (parse) the `Document` which is what happens in the next lines.

Some caveats:

- PDF documents might contain so-called 'subset fonts'. This is when a font is artificially made smaller by throwing out unused letters. ie if a PDF never uses the 'uppercase X' letter then the font does not need to store information on how to render it. Typically, the names of subset fonts are not the same as those of their original font. You might get something like `Courier+AEOKFF`.
- If this happens to be the case, check out the code of `FontNameFilter` and make another version that only checks the name using `startswith`, which out to do the trick.